# Why branch reported as not merged despite on it is merged

Tags: git, merge, git-branch, git-merge

I have branch and all changes at that branch are at master (HEAD). but `git diff master...feature/5492_new_currency` shows me that it is not. Where am I wrong?

```
$ git diff master...feature/5492_new_currency
diff --git a/app/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/lang.po b/app/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/lang.po
index 9274c9e..6b9d1ae 100644
--- a/app/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/lang.po
+++ b/app/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/lang.po
@@ -4531,6 +4531,10 @@ msgstr "$"
 msgid "currency:UZS"
 msgstr "сум."

+# Британский фунт
+msgid "currency:GBP"
+msgstr "£"
+
 msgid "datepicker:prevText"
 msgstr "Пред>"

diff --git a/app/protos/defaults.ini b/app/protos/defaults.ini
index 4742982..4de9ea3 100644
--- a/app/protos/defaults.ini
+++ b/app/protos/defaults.ini
@@ -2,8 +2,8 @@ BASE_DOMAIN                = xxxxx
 INSTANCE_COUNTRY           = ru
 INSTANCE_LANGS             = ru en
 DEFAULT_LANGUAGE           = ru
-# Доступные валюты стран для магазинов: РФ, США, Евро, Казахстан, Украина, Китай, Молдова, Армения,
-INSTANCE_CURRENCY          = RUB USD EUR KZT UAH CNY MDL AMD UZS AZN KGS TJS TMT GEL LVL LTL
+# Доступные валюты стран для магазинов: РФ, США, Евро, Казахстан, Украина, Китай, Молдова, Армения,
+INSTANCE_CURRENCY          = RUB USD EUR KZT UAH CNY MDL AMD UZS AZN KGS TJS TMT GEL LVL LTL GBP

 MAIL_FROM         = xxxxx
 MAIL_FEEDBACK     = xxxxx
kes@backend01:~/site/app$ git branch
  feature/5492_new_currency
* master
  production
kes@backend01:~/site/app$ cat locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/lang.po | grep -A 5 -B 5 'msgid "currency:GBP"'
# Узбекистан
msgid "currency:UZS"
msgstr "сум."

# Британский фунт
msgid "currency:GBP"
msgstr "£"

msgid "datepicker:prevText"
msgstr "Пред>"

kes@backend01:~/site/app$ git branch -d feature/5492_new_currency
warning: deleting branch 'feature/5492_new_currency' that has been merged to
         'refs/remotes/origin/feature/5492_new_currency', but not yet merged to HEAD.
Deleted branch feature/5492_new_currency (was ab38009).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found what problem is:

Someone just `cherry-pick` those changes into master branch.

So despite on changes are same the branch is not at `master`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `git fetch` to see if the repo has updated? You may not have updated it on your computer.

---

Check your repo on the web. If it shows your branch as merged, it is. If it does, force push an update to Github desktop.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No. What you mean? What should I run?

Answer (score 1):

> `git diff master...feature/5492_new_currency` [shows some differences]

The three-dot syntax, `A...B`, has a special meaning in Git.  More precisely, it has *two* special meanings, one exclusive to `git diff`.  (In other Git commands it has its other special meaning.)  For `git diff` (and *only* for `git diff`), `A...B` means:

- First, run `git merge-base --all A B`.  Save its output ID(s) in a variable—let's call this `$base`.  (In shell script you could write `base=$(git merge-base --all A B)` and then `echo $base` to see whether there is just one ID.)
- Then, as long as that outputs just one commit ID, choose that one commit ID, and run: `git diff $base B`.  Otherwise produce some not-useful output.  (This "otherwise" part is a bug.  It's not actually happening here as you would see `diff --cc` in the headers, so we know there was in fact just one ID.)

Since `A` here is `master` and `B` here is `feature/5492_new_currency`, and there is some diff output, that tells me that:

```
git merge-base master feature/5492_new_currency
```

and:

```
git rev-parse feature/5492_new_currency
```

would have produced two different IDs.

That in turn implies that `master` is not an ancestor of `feature/5492_new_currency`.  If it were, the merge base of `master` and `feature/5492_new_currency` would be the *same* commit ID as `feature/5492_new_currency`.

Your next command and its result is actually more directly informative:

> ```
> kes@backend01:~/site/app$ git branch -d feature/5492_new_currency
> warning: deleting branch 'feature/5492_new_currency' that has been merged to
>   'refs/remotes/origin/feature/5492_new_currency', but not yet merged to HEAD.
> Deleted branch feature/5492_new_currency (was ab38009).
> ```

Put together, these two mean that your claim:

> I have branch and all changes at that branch are at master (HEAD)

is wrong!  In particular, this second result proves that given the two IDs that would be produced by:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

and:

```
git rev-parse feature/5492_new_currency
```

the ID from the former is not "less than or equal to" the ID from the latter, i.e., `HEAD` is not an ancestor of `feature/5492_new_currency`.  Assuming `HEAD` is actually a reference to `master`, that in turn means `master` is not an ancestor of `feature/5492_new_currency`, just as we saw from the first command.  It could be "greater than" (i.e., ahead of), but if that were the case, `git diff` would have compared `feature/5492_new_currency` to itself.  So `feature/5492_new_currency` was definitely *not* merged into `master`.  It *was* pushed to its upstream, though (its upstream being `origin/5492_new_currency`).  That is, the ID from the name `feature/5492_new_currency` was "less than or equal to" the ID you can still get from `origin/5492_new_currency`.

Now that your branch-name `feature/5492_new_currency` has been deleted, you will have to do any manipulation you need to apply to your local name `master` using some name other than `feature/5492_new_currency`.  The most straightforward might be to run:

```
$ git checkout master && git merge origin/5492_new_currency
```

which will either fast-forward `master`, or make a new merge commit.  (To force a new merge commit even if fast-forward is possible, use `git merge --no-ff`.)